# Enter on autocomplete item affects submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am using the `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` api to find addresses using autocomplete functionality. When the user is selecting an item by the key and hitting the enter button the submit button is affected instead.

In principle the default button behavior is ok, but not while choosing an element in an autocomplete textbox.

Do I really need to catch the Enter event and check what element has the focus?

Comment: probably easiest (& easy) indeed. I dont know if there is any config to do it otherwise.. `if( /* element has focus, something with activeElement */ ) { event.stopPropagation(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a keydown event and handle things properly when key 13 (Enter) is pressed.